# Dynamic custom asp.net control : ID property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I would like to create a custom control : a numeric textbox.
I followed this tutorial (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42382/Creating-a-Numeric-TextBox-Control) but I'm facing an issue.
I want to create those controls dynamically like that :

```
NumericTextBox _Quantity = new NumericTextBox();
_Quantity.ID = "_Quantity" + id;
_Quantity.Text = "1";
```

However, it is said that there is no definition for the "ID" property in NumericTextBox. Yet, this control is TextBox's child, so it should have the ID property, like the Text's one which works well...

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

[assembly: WebResource("CustomControls.Resources.NumericTextBox.js", "text/javascript")]
namespace CustomControls
{
    [ToolboxData(@"<{0}:NumericTextBox ID="""" Text="""" runat=""server""></{0}:NumericTextBox>")]
    public partial class NumericTextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
    {
        // specific code
    }
}
```

Did I miss something ? If I can make this property work, will the FindControl method work with the custom control ?

Thanks a lot !

**EDIT :**

I have two projects in my solution :

- A class library one, "CustomControls", which contains NumericTextBox.cs
- And my website.

Here is my page's extract code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using CustomControls;

public partial class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void AddItem(Enum type, Enum content)
    {
        string id = (content != null) ? content.ToString() : type.ToString();
        ...

        NumericTextBox _Quantity = new NumericTextBox();
        _Quantity.ID = "_Quantity" + id;
        _Quantity.Text = "1";

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is strange, in my code it works perfectly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ButtonTest2
{
    [ToolboxData(@"<{0}:NumericTextBox ID="""" Text="""" runat=""server""></{0}:NumericTextBox>")]
    public partial class NumericTextBox : TextBox
    {

    }
}
```

Instancing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace ButtonTest2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NumericTextBox tb = new NumericTextBox();
            tb.ID = "123";
        }
    }
}
```

Do you miss some usings in the class where you create the `NumericTextBox` *instance*?

**EDIT**
`FindControl` should work with your custom control.

Comment: Thanks for your response ! I'm using CustomControls' namespace so I thought it would work... I edited my first post with my page's code ;)

Comment: Hmm, if i copy your code to my solution, it works. What happens if you try to create an instance of a simple `TextBox` in your `AddItem`-Method? Do you than have a ID-property? Maybe you forget to reference some assemblies...

Comment: Yes I have =( There is actually no ID property in NumericTextBox but it should be inherited... I can edit the first post with the control's code. I added CustomControls reference to the website project, but the strangest is that Text property works, but not ID property.

Comment: @Flash_Back do a normal `TextBox` has an `ID`-Property? (Only for testing)

Comment: Yes it has, no problem with the normal TextBox

Comment: @Flash_Back One more question :) Does only Intellisense sais, that you have no `ID`-Attribute, or can't you even compile?

Comment: I juste found out why, so clumsy... Before creating the control in the class library, I tried to add it in the project itself. So I had another class named NumericTextBox and that's why the error occurred... I'm so sorry I found it now, I will accept your answer anyway, and thanks a lot for answering me !